# ¿Como obtner el valor de un input radio? solo haciendo click en el boton radio y no utilizar formulario

Tags: javascript, input, radiobutton

este es mi script no se mucho de javascript asi que me fui por lo mas sencillo cae mencionar que no me funciona esto

```
<script>

      var prueba = document.querySelector('input[name="pro"]:checked').value;

      console.log(prueba);
    </script>
```

este es mi html

```
<input type="radio" name="pro" value="400" >prueba
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo sería utilizar una función en el método onClick y realizar el proceso que ocupes

```js
function myFunction(valor){
  console.log(valor)
}
```

```html
<p> Opciones: </p>  
<input type="radio" name="opciones" id="verano" value="verano" onclick="myFunction('verano')" >Verano<br>   
<input type="radio" name="opciones" id="invierno" value="invierno" onclick="myFunction('invierno')" >Invierno<br>
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda aprovechando su amabilidad en caso de que el valor lo pusiera dinamicamente con php como se lo paso por parametro intente con this pero no me funciono